# Share extension to share a number from recent calls

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

Working on the first swift app, and stuck in "share extension". Trying to share a phone number from recent calls log to an app for background task.

Thought to do it in this way, once user enter profile of a number from recent call log:
[image]

Will see the icon of my app:
[image]

Now want to get the phone number and the country code to do that task, current code is:

```
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Want to get selected phone number only and print it on the console for testing
        print("Test\n")
    }
}
```

How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share more of the code in order to get an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your App's icon is used. From [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html):

> In iOS, a custom Action extension uses a template image version of its containing app’s icon, which you must provide.
>
> iOS Share extensions automatically employ the containing app’s icon. If you provide a separate icon in your Share extension target, Xcode ignores it. For all other app extension types, you must provide an icon that matches the containing app’s icon.

Comment: Thank you, but Its not about the icon, its about getting the shared number